# unable to login to magento2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to develop a new plugin for Magento2. I have tried to follow this [article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-on-localhost/) in order to install Magento2 on my local machine. The problem is after installing it, I couldn't login to the admin panel.
It sometimes redirects me to the login page immediately after clicking the login button, or it says the account sign-in was incorrect or your account disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later), i have tried these solutions so far but nothing works:

1. Deleting the value of the `web/cookies/cookie_admin`, `web/cookies/cookie_httponly`, `web/cookies/cookie_lifetime`, and `web/cookies/cookie_path` configs from core_config_data table. (actually i didn’t find these keys in the table, so i couldn’t try this solution)
2. Executing `php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1`
3. Setting the value of ‘`web/secure/base_url`’ and ‘`web/unsecure/base_url`’ to here is located in my
4. localhost ‘http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/’
5. Switching to developer mode
6. Unlocking admin account (btw, it wasn’t locked)
7. Creating a new admin account
8. Changing the password of existing admin account
9. Disabling `Magento_TwoFactoryAuth` module
10. Increasing max_input_vars value to 10,000, memory_limit to 4G, and max_execution_time to 18,000
11. Changing the host in env.php from localhost to 127.0.0.1
12. Enabling Soap, Sockets, Sodium, and Xsl extensions
13. Deleting `var` and `generated` folders
14. failures_num is 0 and first_failure is NULL in admin_user table
15. Changing the part of the code that responsible for comparing received password with actual password in the compareStrings function in vendor/laminas/laminas-crypt/src/Utils.php class

```
if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return hash_equals($expected, $actual); }
```

with

```
if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return true; }
```

I'm using php v8.1.10

Any suggestions?